# Learning servlets: HTTP Status 404 - /Controller

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

(Resolved!)

I'm following a tutorial on servlets but I'm getting stuck quite early. For some reason I get a 404 as soon as the controller is called (Controller.java below).

The idea is that the form in index.jsp should call a controller (form action="Controller") in order to determine which page the information in the form should be sent to, depending on which button in the form was pressed (currently only one, confirmButton).

However, I keep getting a 404 when Controller is called.

...help?

index.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a simple HTML page that has a form in it.
<form action="Controller">
    <p>
        If there is a value for the hobby in the query
        string, then it is used to initialize the hobby
        element.
    <p>
        Hobby: <input type="text" name="hobby"
                      value="${param.hobby}">
        <input type="submit" name="confirmButton"
               value="Confirm">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.Controller</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/controller/Controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Controller.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String address;

        if (request.getParameter("processButton") != null) {
            address = "Process.jsp";
        } else if (request.getParameter("confirmButton") != null) {
            address = "Confirm.jsp";
        } else {
            address = "index.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

placement of files:

```
src/controller/Controller.java
web/WEB-INF/classes/controller/Controller.class
```

Comment: Servlets are painful. I'm sorry.

Comment: You don't have a method of submit in your form.Add `<form method="POST">`!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this since yesterday, but of course I find the answer myself as soon as I post the question.

Changes:

(1) placement of files

```
src/servletController/Controller.java
web/servletController/index.jsp
web/WEB-INF/classes/servletController/Controller.class
```

(2) minor changes to web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletController.Controller</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletController/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Edit: not actually 100% sure why it works, but I've decided I'm not a fan of servlets.